# Google Colab Pro "Your session crashed after using all available RAM" on the simplest task

Tags: numpy, crash, google-colaboratory, ram

I have my data in a (93894, 8320) numpy array.  All good so far.  When I go to np.concatenate it with another array that's (93894, 1), it crashes Colab every single time, even though it's handled the larger tasks just fine.

```
model_data = np.concatenate((model_data_minus_labels, all_labels), axis=1)
```

I've switched to high-RAM runtime, tried switching from CPU to GPU and back, and am using Colab Pro.

Comment: If your array is 64 bit floating point, it uses over 6 gigabytes.  The concatenation operation requires making a copy, so, at least for a short time, you will need over 12 gigabytes.  How much RAM is availabe in your Colab session?

Comment: Ah ok.  Colab Pro doesn't have a fixed amount of RAM available because it reallocates it to different users based on demand, but it seems to crash after I've used in the 20-22 GB range.

Comment: @mojones101 did you find any solution to it.

Comment: @LalitJain I did not.  I wound up structuring my data differently and never solved this problem.